# Why teach factorization of integers?

Tags: undergraduate-education, student-motivation

Why is factorization of integers important in a first number theory course at an undergraduate level? Where is factorization used in real life? Are there examples which have a real impact? I am looking for examples which will motivate students.

Comment: Many commonly used cryptography algorithms (e.g., the ones you use to shop online while keeping your credit card number secure) depend on the fact that there is no efficient algorithm for factoring large numbers. Factorization is one of the classical problems of mathematics; it's discussed in Euclid.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you describe the context a bit more. At what level are the students? Is this about secondary education and a first encounter with number theory or about a first course in number theory at the university level.

Comment: I find that it makes quite a bit of mental arithmetic much easier.

Comment: A first course in number theory at undergraduate level.

Comment: @matqkks: Is there a particular textbook you're using (or intending to use)?

Comment: You're worried about "real life" in a *number theory* course?

Comment: As a professional software developer, I *wish* I'd done number theory at a higher level. If you ever have doubt about real-world application of Math, think no further than computing.

Comment: Are you asking about *algorithms* for integer factorization, or about the *existence* (and uniqueness) of prime factorizations?

Answer (score 8):

Luckily there's a [book](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem?item=STML-68)

> *The Joy of Factoring*.
>   Samuel S. Wagstaff, Jr.

that answers this exact question -- see the review on the linked page.  In addition to cryptography, the book motivates an interest in factoring via repunits, repeating decimal fractions, perfect numbers, Gauss's interest in factoring and the Cunningham project.

Comment: I think readers might easily be misled by the statement that the book "answers this exact question." To clarify, the book very briefly discusses said topics in 10 pages of the first chapter, titled "Why Factor Integers". But this is not the primary topic of the book. Further, rather than ancient recreational applications, most number theorists or algebraists would list much deeper reasons for studying factorization.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I took the phrase "this exact question" from the review.  I don't have the book in front of me and haven't looked at it for quite a while, but in addition to the "recreational" motivation in the first chapter, I seem to remember the fourth chapter (How factors are used) and the seventh chapter (Elliptic curves) provide further reasons for why one might study factoring (in the context of number theory).

Answer (score 6):

There is (at least) one significant reason behind the factorization: the relevant intuition. For example

- it allows you to think of natural numbers as vectors (e.g. $\gcd$ and $\mathrm{lcm}$ become component-wise $\min$ and $\max$);
- it allows you to think of the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) as base-reencoding from prime-based number system.

There are also other good reasons, like the problem's importance in cryptography or as basic example of [unique factorization domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain) or [principal ideal domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain). Still, the intuitions and mental tools factorization provides seem enough of a reason by itself.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 4):

As far as "real life" goes, it's fairly boring, but I honestly think the best use is simply number sense.

It's not **complete** prime factorization that's important, IMO it's not super important to your average undergrad that $288 = 3^2 \cdot 2^5$, but the general process of $288 = 2 \cdot 144 = 2 \cdot 12 \cdot 12$ will make it much easier to multiply 3-4 digit numbers in your head. Or the inverse, simply that "oh, 288 is about 12 times bigger than 24". While that specific number may not be useful, the general method is.

Of course, depending on your subfield of mathematics that's not necessarily an overwhelmingly useful skill, but it's useful for one-the-fly calculations in "real life". As much as we like to make fun of them, "if Sally has 12 apples..." problems do come up occasionally in planning meetings and the like, and the ability to get a quick intuitive breakdown of numbers can speed things up.

Answer (score 2):

> Where is factorization used in real life?

It is used when we simplify fractions.  For example, to simplify $\frac{15}{51}$ to $\frac{5}{17}$ one must know that $15=3\times 5$ and $51=3\times 17$.

It is used when we need to know how many objects having a common value are needed to get a given value.  For example, to find out how many $16$-US-fluid-ounce cups of a softdrink are needed to fill up a $1$-US-gallon container, you need to know that $1$ US gallon = $128$ US fluid ounces = $8\times 16$ US fluid ounces.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison of number systems: Why is the decimal system *mathematically* worse than the duodecimal system? Why is the sexigesimal system so useful, that it's still used even if nearly everything else (outside of the US, Liberia and Burma) is decimal?

The answer is the factoring of these numbers.

Comment: I wouldn't say that decimal system is worse than the duodecimal, in fact the popularity of the former is an argument that it's perhaps the other way around.

Comment: @dtldarek Ah, I forgot to add `mathematically`.

Answer (score 0):

Factoring into primes is a very fundamental operation in number theory. It pops up all over the place.

Comment: While to the point in my opinion, this answer is so terse that I suspect it is not very helpful for somebody actually asking the question, and it could be helpful if you would include some examples. (The votes are not mine.)